# Parameterized test with ClasspathSuite

Tags: java, junit4

I need to run my test multiple times in succession (4 times, one for each browser I am testing with WebDriver). I understand that this is a use case for parameterized tests. However, I am utilizing `ClasspathSuite` and so it seems I cannot specify multiple `@RunWith` annotations.

Is there any way I can get my test to run multiple times and send some sort of parameter (like 0 - 3 for the 4 runs I need) to the test?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution: I parameterized each test case the same (using find an replace in Eclipse to add the same code to every test case. Then I had set up my Code cleanup and formatting so when I ran them it returned my code to a pretty state (as my insert had been all on one line)

Answer (score 0):

I just faced this, `ClasspathSuite` handles this just fine. The trick is to use these annotations in the little dummy project that finds & launches tests (across other projects):

```
@RunWith(ClasspathSuite.class)
@SuiteTypes(RUN_WITH_CLASSES)
```

Then any test requiring a specific runner just uses that runner directly, such as `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)`

See section **"Running other RunWith-Suites"** here: https://github.com/takari/takari-cpsuite

Due to a wide range of tests, I opted to use all options:

```
@SuiteTypes({RUN_WITH_CLASSES, TEST_CLASSES, JUNIT38_TEST_CLASSES})
```

(The default appears to be just TEST_CLASSES.)